# how to extract fitted values after multiple imputation

Tags: lm, predict, imputation

```
busan<-subset(influ_busan, select = c(CNT,temp_min,temp_diff,humid_mean,hpa_mean,rad_mean,wind_mean,o3))

new_busan<-mice(busan, seed=12345, n=5)

lm_busan <- with(new_busan,lm(CNT~temp_min+temp_diff+humid_mean+hpa_mean+rad_mean+wind_mean+o3))

summary(lm_busan)
busan_predict<-data.frame(fitted.values(lm_busan))
```

This is my simply version syntax. I use multiple imputation for NA and After multiple imputation, I want to extract fitted values. However I can't extract fitted values, how can I extract fitted values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `extract_imputations` function from my version of `mice`; hopefully will be incorporated into the main `mice` version shortly:

see: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/pull/51

```
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/mice")
library(mice)
new_busan <- mice(busan, seed= 12345, m=2)
busan_predict <- extract_imputations(busan, new_busan$imp, j= 1)
busan_predict <- extract_imputations(busan, new_busan$imp, j= 2)
```

**Edit** Apparently, I didn't read the mice documentation thoroughly enough. This functionality already existed in mice -- `mice::complete`

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks to you, I solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @yurijung Then, ideally, you should accept and upvote the answer

Comment: @yurijung I know this is a very old post, but how did you end up getting the fitted values? I currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @TengkuHanis check the pull request listed in my answer... see `?mice::complete`